# How to add ItemClick on PagedListAdapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

Here is my first time to apply MVVM concept to my Android Application. I follow the steps at the referenced article

https://medium.com/swlh/realtime-firestore-pagination-on-android-with-mvvm-b5e30cea437

And I am managed to load data successfully. When it comes to implementing the onclick event at the row of my RecyclerView List, it comes out that there has no onlick response .

Would you please suggest the  better method to implement the onCLick method given that I have applied PageListAdapter?

When I study the PageListAdapter documentation on Android, it seems no clue for me to implement the onclick method.

```
class MovieViewModel(movieRepository: MovieRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val viewModelJob = SupervisorJob()
    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)
    var selected: MutableLiveData<RealtimeMovie>? = null

    private val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setPrefetchDistance(10)
            .setPageSize(20)
            .build()

    val records: LiveData<PagedList<RealtimeMovie>> =
            LivePagedListBuilder<String, RealtimeMovie>(
                    MovieDataSource.Factory(movieRepository, uiScope),
                    config
            ).build()

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
class MovieAdapter : PagedListAdapter<RealtimeMovie, MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder>(
        object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RealtimeMovie>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(old: RealtimeMovie, new: RealtimeMovie): Boolean =
                    old.id == new.id

            override fun areContentsTheSame(old: RealtimeMovie, new: RealtimeMovie): Boolean =
                    old == new
        }
) {

    private lateinit var onItemClick: (movie: RealtimeMovie) -> Unit

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.list_movie,
                parent,
                false
        )
        return MovieViewHolder(view)
    }


    infix fun setOnItemClick(onClick: (movie: RealtimeMovie) -> Unit) {

        this.onItemClick = onClick
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val record = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(record)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { onItemClick(record!!) }
    }

    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: MovieViewHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
        holder.apply {
            txtRecordName.text = ""
            crdRecord.isEnabled = true
            crdRecord.setCardBackgroundColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                            view.context,
                            android.R.color.white
                    )
            )
            viewHolderDisposables.clear()
        }
    }

    inner class MovieViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val viewHolderDisposables = CompositeDisposable()

        val crdRecord by lazy { view.findViewById<MaterialCardView>(R.id.crd_record) }
        val txtRecordName by lazy { view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_record_name) }

        fun bind(RealtimeMovie: RealtimeMovie?) {
            RealtimeMovie?.let {
                it.record
                        .subscribeBy(
                                onNext = {
                                    txtRecordName.text = it.title

                                },
                                onError = {
                                    // Handle error here
                                    // Record maybe deleted
                                }
                        )
                        .addTo(viewHolderDisposables)
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Here is my fragment : 
..

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MovieViewModel::class.java)
viewModel.records.observe(this, Observer {
    swpRecords.isRefreshing = false
    recordsAdapter.submitList(it)
    recordsAdapter.setOnItemClick {
        print("movie : ${it.id}"   )
        print("movie : ${it.record}"   )
    }
})
```

Comment: It is a late response since I just encountered the same problem just recently, the hack I found was that the problem lies in the onBindViewHolder method when you are passing the argument in the onItemClick method, you should use getItem(position) rather than the variable record which will always return the last element on the pagedList rather than the element you clicked on. Then you implement the interface in your fragment.